# Liquibase compare and update databases

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, liquibase-hibernate

I would like to use liquibase in my spring boot app. My requirement is that I have a dummy schema which is populated with tables every time I change the entity classes. This is done by hibernate's ddl create. There are many identical schemas to the dummy schema with data. I want those schemas to be compared with the dummy schema on update and be synced without affecting my data. How can I achieve this? I could not find a tutorial anywhere. If there is one please do give me the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this tutorial explains what your are looking for
[baeldung maven liquibase plugin](http://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app)

In section 5.3 is a description on how you can get a changlog file with differences between two databases.

Comment: I need to compare and update hundreds of schemas. Is there a way to do that in a single run?